# Checking to see if multiple ENV variables exist

Tags: python

Is there a more optimal way I can check to see if multiple ENV variables exist with customized exceptions?  Perhaps a way to match a group of EVN variables, and then have the exception self-reference the variable name in its output?

```
if os.environ.get('USERNAME') is not None:
    self.username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
else:
    raise CustomException('Environment variable USERNAME not set')  
if os.environ.get('PASSWORD') is not None:
    self.password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
else:
    raise CustomException('Environment variable PASSWORD not set')
```

I am using Python 2.7.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#
# ENV vars you want to go over
#
env_vars = 'HOME,PATH,NONEXISTS'.split(',')

for evar in env_vars:
    # Loop will create it as: self.$evar = os.environ.get(evar)
    
    if evar not in os.environ:
        # Will skip: NONEXISTS
        continue

        # or if you want to raise exception
        raise ValueError('Environment variable "%s" was not set' % evar)

    # setattr: will create a dynamic attribute for "self"    
    # self.home = ...
    # self.path = ...
    # evar.lower() => so we'll have self.home vs self.HOME
    setattr(self, evar.lower(), os.environ.get(evar))
```

In general, just note that you don't need to verify if it's "None" in Python, so

```
# Replace this
if os.environ.get('USERNAME') is not None:

# With this, the default of get => is None, and None won't pass "if"
if os.environ.get('USERNAME'):

# Will create an exception if USERNAME doesn't exists
if os.environ['USERNAME']
```

Hope it helps ...

Answer (score -1):

You could always use a loop with a three items list:

```
for data in [
    ["USERNAME", "username", CustomException],
    ["PASSWORD", "password", CustomException]
]:
    env_var = os.environ.get(data[0])


    if env_var:
        setattr(self, data[1], env_var)
    else:
        # Should work, cannot check due to not having actually Python installed.
        raise data[2]("Environment variable %s not set" % data[0])
```

If you don't like using indexes, you could replace the items by dicts like this to have a more consistent access if you change order:

```
{"env_var_name": "USERNAME", "attr": "username", "exception_cls": CustomException}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put all the environment lookups in a `try:` block:

```
try:
    self.username= os.environ['USERNAME']
    self.password= os.environ['PASSWORD']
except KeyError as e:
    raise CustomException('Environment variable {} not set'.format(e.args[0]))
```

Comment: If neither are set, it shows "USERNAME" as not set.

Comment: @EthanB Well, yeah. That's the same thing your code does.

Comment: What I am trying to avoid is creating a match statement for each ENV variable.  I have ~10 total.  But if more than one does not exist, I want all the non-present entries to be shown in the exception.